# Using Array in Azure Function Application Settings

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm using `appsettings.json` for the configuration of my Azure Function (netcoreapp3.1, running on a Windows machine).

In the `appsettings.json` file there is a array with settings:

```
{
    "ArraySettings": [
        {
            "ArraySettingProperty1": "ArraySetting1Value1",
            "ArraySettingProperty2": "ArraySetting1Property2"
        },
        {
            "ArraySettingProperty1": "ArraySetting2Value1",
            "ArraySettingProperty2": "ArraySetting2Property2"
        }
    ],
    "SingleSetting": "SingleValue"
}
```

It works fine if I run the Azure Function locally. But it seems not to work on Azure although the `appsettings.json` file was deployt and can be found by the Azure Function.

In `Startup.cs`:

```
private IConfiguration InitializeConfiguration(IFunctionsHostBuilder functionsHostBuilder)
        {
            ExecutionContextOptions executionContextOptions = functionsHostBuilder
               .Services
               .BuildServiceProvider()
               .GetService<IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions>>()
               .Value;

            return new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(executionContextOptions.AppDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
        }
```

This is what I already tried (without success):

1. Copying the settings to the `Values` section of the `local.settings.json` file
2. Adding the settings to the Application Settings on Azure (with and without commenting out the `appsettings.json` config) in the following key formats:

   2.1 ArraySettings:ArraySettingProperty1:0

   2.2 ArraySettings__ArraySettingsProperty1__0

   2.3 Values__ArraySettings__ArraySettingsProperty1__0

Why do the array settings work locally but not on Azure? How can I make them work on Azure? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try setting them like the following in configuration settings in your app service:

```
Key: ArraySettings__0__ArraySettingProperty1

Value: ArraySetting1Value1

Key: ArraySettings__0__ArraySettingProperty2

Value: ArraySetting1Value2

Key: ArraySettings__1__ArraySettingProperty1

Value: ArraySetting1Value1

Key: ArraySettings__1__ArraySettingProperty2

Value: ArraySetting1Value2

Key: SingleSetting

Value: SingleValue
```

If your app service is deployed on Windows, you can use `:` as a delimiter instead of `__`. However `__` works on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```cs
public class MyOptions
{
      public List<string> MyArray { get; set; }
}

// local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "MyOptions__MyArray__0": "foo",
    "MyOptions__MyArray__1": "bar"
  }
}

// In startup.cs:
builder.Services.Configure<MyOptions>(configuration.GetSection("MyOptions"));
```